# Render to texture and render to renderbuffer at the same time

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use such code to setup my framebuffer:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer_) ;

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer_);

if (!colorBuffer_)
{
    NSLog(@"glGenRenderbuffers() failed");
    break;
}

[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:drawable_];
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width_);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &height_);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

if (!fbo)
{
    NSLog(@"glGenFramebuffers() failed");
    break;
}

CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, self.context, NULL, &textureCache_);
if (err)
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate %d", err);
}
CFDictionaryRef empty; // empty value for attr value.
CFMutableDictionaryRef attrs;
empty = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, // our empty IOSurface properties dictionary
                           NULL,
                           NULL,
                           0,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                           &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
attrs = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                  1,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                  &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionarySetValue(attrs,
                     kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey,
                     empty);

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                    (int)width_,
                    (int)height_,
                    kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                    attrs,
                    &renderTarget_);

err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage (kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                    textureCache_, renderTarget_,
                                                    NULL, // texture attributes
                                                    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                                    GL_RGBA, // opengl format
                                                    (int)width_,
                                                    (int)height_,
                                                    GL_BGRA, // native iOS format
                                                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                                    0,
                                                    &renderTexture_);
if (err)
{
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate %d", err);
}

CFRelease(attrs);
CFRelease(empty);

glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(renderTexture_), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture_));
checkForErrors();

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

NSLog(@"%u", CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture_));

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(renderTexture_), 0);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer_);
```

I want to render to texture and render to renderbuffer (to see results of rendering at the screen) at the same time. But this code is not working. I think that I can't use `glFramebufferTexture2D` and `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` at the same time. Am I right? how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You are right in that you cannot attach both a texture and a renderbuffer to the same attachment point to automatically render into both.

Just render it to the texture and then draw a screen-sized textured quad to the screen to show it. And of course, remember to unbind your texture (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`) while rendering into it, which at the moment you don't.

Or do it the other way around by rendering the results to the screen as usual and copy those results into the texture using `glCopyTexSubImage2D`. But in the end you won't get around a copy, be it indirectly in the form of drawing a textured quad or a direct framebuffer-to-texture copy.

**EDIT:** You might also solve this using multiple render targets, by attaching the texture and the renderbuffer to different color attachments and putting out the same resulting color on multiple channels in the fragment shader (using `gl_FragData[i]` instead of `gl_FragColor`). But I'm not sure if that would really buy you anything, plus it requires your shaders to be aware of the double rendering. And in the end I'm not sure ES actually supports mutliple render targets.

Comment: I have a app similar to apple's GLPAint example(with kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking = YES). Ant it is too expensive to render to texture and draw textured quad at the same time. Are there some another way to do it fast?

Comment: @miksayer I listed every obvious way to do it. Do you really need to update the texture each frame? If not, then just keep rendering to the screen and only use `glCopyTexSubImage2D` when neccessary. I don't know the semantics of this GLPaint app, but if it is some standard paint application, you only need to update the actual image (texture) when you need it, or at least when you are finished with interactively drawing something (e.g. when releasing the mouse/finger/whatever).

Comment: i've tried method with glCopyTexSubImage2D. But I don't have any performance increases(before i used glReadPixels to get screenshot).

Comment: @miksayer Well, `glReadPixels` (followed by `glTexSubImage2D`, I guess) is definitely the wrong approach, since it makes a roundtrip to the CPU which is unneccessary. Though, it is still dependent on your system and application if there is a difference in performance, maybe your implementation even makes a roundtrip over CPU with `glCopyTexSubImage2D`, too, but I would really doubt it. I also don't have much experience with the actual hardware of ES devices. Nevertheless, `glCopyTexSubImage2D` is conceptually more correct (and in worst-case performance-equivalent) than `glReadPixels`.

Comment: i want to get only buffer with pixels from screen. And i want to do it fast. glReadPixels and glCopyTexSubImage2D don't give me such performance that i want :(